# ¿Error Clickdimensions formulario enviado no aparece en PostedForms?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, crm, dynamics-ax, dynamics-crm

buenos días. He publicado en Dynamics un formulario de contacto, le he indicado la thankyou page...etc. Pero me pasa una cosa, lo relleno y me envía a la thankyou perfecto, pero cuando entro a clickdimensions a "posted forms" no me sale nada, como si no lo hubiera enviado ¿sabéis porque pueda ser? ¿me falta algo? Muchas gracias

Comment: Necesito ayuda urgente es para un cliente gracias!

Comment: Hola Nacho Bienvenido/a a [StackOverFlow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)  Mira [ask] y [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad. Además deberías realizar el [tour] para entender mejor como funciona el sitio.